# Console not opening after weblogic server 10.3.6 installation in UNIX server

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, unix, oracle11g

I tried weblogic server 10.3.6 in remote unix server using putty.According to logs the server is started and is in running mode.But when I try to open the console in browser it shows server not found page. Please help me regarding this issue.

**LOGS**

The system is vulnerable to security attacks, since it trusts certificates signed by the demo trusted CA.

> < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:35 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> <
>   Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=thawte Primary Root CA -
>   G3,OU=(c) 2008 thawte\, Inc. - For authorized use
>   only,OU=Certification Services Division,O=thawte\, Inc.,C=US". The
>   loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing
>   exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object:
>   1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:35 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring the trusted CA certificate
>   "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems
>   Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate
>   list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in
>   the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14,
>   2015 6:20:35 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring
>   the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class
>   2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services
>   GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a
>   certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the
>   AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015
>   6:20:35 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring the
>   trusted CA certificate "CN=GlobalSign,O=GlobalSign,OU=GlobalSign Root
>   CA - R3". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a
>   certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the
>   AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015
>   6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring the
>   trusted CA certificate "OU=Security Communication RootCA2,O=SECOM
>   Trust Systems CO.\,LTD.,C=JP". The loading of the trusted certificate
>   list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in
>   the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14,
>   2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring
>   the trusted CA certificate "CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification
>   Authority,OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use
>   only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of
>   the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception
>   PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object:
>   1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring the trusted CA certificate
>   "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading of the
>   trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX:
>   Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object:
>   1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < Security> < BEA-090898> < Ignoring the trusted CA certificate
>   "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust
>   Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of
>   the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception
>   PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object:
>   1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>    < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < Server> < BEA-002613> < Channel "Default" is now listening on
>   139.76.232.14:8006 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>  < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < WebLogicServer> < BEA-000329> <
>   Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "WLS5" running
>   in Production Mode>  < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Error> < Server>
>   < BEA-002606> < Unable to create a server socket for listening on
>   channel "DefaultSecure". The address 139.76.232.14 might be incorrect
>   or another process is using port 7002: java.net.BindException: Address
>   already in use.>    < Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> <
>   WebLogicServer> < BEA-000365> < Server state changed to RUNNING>    <
>   Jul 14, 2015 6:20:36 AM EDT> < Notice> < WebLogicServer> < BEA-000360>
>   < Server started in RUNNING mode>

Comment: What port number are you using?

Comment: I gave 8006 as port number